# lookup not working in header inside report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I have report rdlc VS2017 with two dataSet, one for data and other for a language I user  lookup for change column header using `lookup`.

```
=Lookup("ID",Fields!Column.Value,Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet2")
```

But it's not working. When I try to run the report it's loading failed.

Please Help Me.